# Fast search and replace of styles in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, ole-automation

I have the need to automate conversion of html files into MS Word files, and as part of it I want to remove all ocorances of style `Normal (Web)` and replace them with just `Normal`.

I'm using the following

```
$find = $word.Selection.Find
$find.Style = $word.ActiveDocument.Styles.Item("Normal (Web)")
$find.Forward = $True
$find.Format = $True
while ($word.Selection.Find.Execute())
{
    $word.Selection.Style = $word.ActiveDocument.Styles.Item("Normal")
    $null = $word.Selection.EndKey(5)
}
```

which *works* but is slow. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Your code is already the fastest option when using the Word object model via COM automation. You could only get faster when working on the generated (docx) file itself, e.g. using Microsoft's OpenXML SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an approch which doesn't replace, but has the desired effect:

```
$style = $word.ActiveDocument.Styles.Item("Normal (Web)")
$style.Delete()
```